# Getting into and staying the UK for 6 months or less as an American

Tags: uk, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

If I am an American and want to come to the UK for an extended visit, have plenty of money saved, and plan to be a "tourist," do I require a return ticket, or can I just buy a one-way ticket? I have a place to stay, with a friend, and plan to stay as long as my passport allows (up to 6 months or less). In that situation, what would you recommend?

Comment: You already basically asked this question and got reasonable answers.  Especially about your boyfriend (which you don't mention here) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152506/can-i-use-a-one-way-ticket-to-come-to-the-uk-or-do-i-need-to-show-a-return-tick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a one-way ticket to come to the UK? Or do I need to show a return ticket to be able to get in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152506/can-i-use-a-one-way-ticket-to-come-to-the-uk-or-do-i-need-to-show-a-return-tick)

Comment: @Nij Both questions are the same OP as I alluded to

Comment: Please learn how duplicate flagging works. @PeterM

Answer (score 2):

Before last year we would say that you should expect a lot of scrutiny at the border if you arrive without a return ticket and say you want to stay for the maximum allowable time, but if you can prove your finances are such that you do not need to work while in the UK (or, preferably, ever again in your life) and you can support yourself, then you would probably be OK.

These days you'll just swipe through the ePassport gates and you're unlikely to speak to immigration at all, but there is a small chance that the gates will kick you out to see a human being. In that case, the above applies.

Comment: How do we know she's flying to an airport equipped with e-passport gates?

Comment: @Crazydre Oh, we don't know that, but it would have to be a rather odd itinerary to avoid passing through an airport with e-passport gates. Belfast, maybe?

Comment: Or STansted. Has e-gates, but not open to non-EU/EFTA citizens yet